# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/mukunda/.ionic/helper.log'

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have created an ionic myApp.then I run ionic serve. but I got error please anyone give a solution for this issue

```
   mukunda@mukunda:~/Desktop/myApp$ ionic serve
   Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 
   '/home/mukunda/.ionic/helper.log'mukunda@mukunda:~/Desktop/myApp$ ^C
   mukunda@mukunda:~/Desktop/myApp$
```

Comment: run your command prompt as administrator.

Comment: @AakashGarg thank you, it's working fine now

Comment: Can i post it as answer?

Comment: Kavya please mark my answer below as answer if it helped

Comment: yes you can post

Comment: Posted below please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Run your command prompt as administrator to resolve this.